# How to handle Response body is (No content )

Tags: javascript, ajax, response, httpresponse, http-status-code-200

I am using Ajax Post method , my url doesn't have response body and response status is 200 still generate a error, How to handle it ?

Comment: can you update with some sample code

Comment: Before executing ajax press `F12` in keyboard & check the `response` tab under `Network`. so you can see what your are getting as response. Also confirm that you are sending a reponse from the URL set in ajax.